# Extracting Usable Info From datetime field in php/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to format a datetime variable with the following code:

```
$passed_time = $stu_quiz->c_date_time;
$passed_time_string = date_format($passed_time, 'M-d-Y');
```

For some reason, if I print $passed_time_string, the output is blank, but if I print out $passed_time, I get the date (in the format 2011-06-15 21:43:09).

Why is the date_format method not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`date_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function expects a "DateTime" object that is created using [`date_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

**Example:**

```
$passed_time = date_create($stu_quiz->c_date_time);
$passed_time_string = date_format($passed_time, 'M-d-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for just date()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The `date()` function expects a timestamp, not the string representation of a date. In the example above, `date()` wouldn't work.

Comment: date(strtotime($passed_time)) would tho

Comment: Yes... but your answer didn't include that and it's very important. Otherwise, the OP would have ended up with the same problem.

Comment: Fair enough. three extra characters needed to respond :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have PHP 5.3 and cannot use the `DateTime` class, try this:

```
$passed_time_string = date("M-d-Y", strtotime($passed_time));
```

First it converts your original MySQL time to a unix timestamp, then formats it as M-d-Y